# kubectl timeout after Ubuntu VM (hyper-v) reboot

Tags: hyper-v, kubernetes

I'm setting up single node K8s cluster following [this guide](https://blog.radwell.codes/2021/05/provisioning-single-node-kubernetes-cluster-using-kubeadm-on-ubuntu-20-04/) using kubeadm.
The cluster is working fine (=I can deploy the test app), but after VM reboot the kubectl cannot connect to the server, I get timeouts.

The VM eth0 has a 172.20.49.238/20 ip address. The host machine (win 10) has a vEthernet adapter with ip address 172.20.48.1/20, which is the default switch for the Hyper-V, the VM is connected on. So this works fine, the VM has connectivity to the outside world.

The K8s server in the VM is configured with server: https://192.168.94.30:6443 (in /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf). From the VM I cannot ping 192.168.94.30. Also I tried opening https://192.168.94.30:6443 from a browser in the VM, e.g., to troubleshoot TLS connection, and it timeouts, too.
It looks like some connectivity/networking issue.

kubelet and etcd services are up and running.

Any ideas what is this 192.168.*.* network coming from? Why the server is reachable after setting up the VM and following the guide, but it does not work after VM restart?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `kubeadm init` chose the wrong (internal) IP that changes every reboot.

Try adding `--apiserver-advertise-address=172.20.49.238` when you do `kubeadm init` to tell kubeadm to use the correct VM's IP.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/_print/#initializing-your-control-plane-node